# We can't write $\mathbb{R}P^{n}=\mathbb{R}P\times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}P$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

please help me to find answer this question,

Why can't we write,
$\mathbb{R}P^{n}=\mathbb{R}P\times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}P$

if $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ is real projective space?

I know (in geometry) $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ is projective space of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. it is real line if space is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and is a real plane if space is $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and go on.

I also know (in algebraic geometry) this space is equivalence classes of this relation

$(x_1,\ldots , x_n) \sim (y_1,\ldots , y_n) \longleftrightarrow (x_1,\ldots , x_n)=\lambda (y_1,\ldots , y_n) $

such that $\lambda \neq 0$

Comment: In algebraic geometry, $\mathbb{P}^2_k \neq \mathbb{P}^1_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^2_k $ because the first scheme has Picard group $\mathbb{Z}$ and the second has $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: A silly comment that may nevertheless elucidate things: it's $\mathbb R (P^n)$, not $(\mathbb R P)^n$.

Comment: Compute $b_1(., Z/2Z)$. The LHS has $b_1=1$ the  RHS has $b_1=n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As topological spaces, for example, $\Bbb RP^2\neq\Bbb RP^1\times\Bbb RP^1$. Note that $\Bbb RP^1$ is just the circle $S^1$, so $\Bbb RP^1\times\Bbb RP^1$ is a torus. On the other hand $\Bbb RP^2$ is a nonorientable surface.

Edit: a more elementary answer is that $\Bbb RP^2\neq\Bbb RP^1\times\Bbb RP^1$ as sets. We often write, for example, $\Bbb R^3=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^2$: even though elements of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^2$ are technically pairs $(a,(b,c))$, there is an obvious enough way to ignore parenthesis and identify this element with $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3$. On the other hand, you cannot take an element $[a:b:c]\in\Bbb RP^3$ and consider it as an element $([a],[b:c])\in\Bbb RP^1\times\Bbb RP^2$. For example, consider $[0:0:1]$.